# Courses of action after having started to strip the threading on a bolt

Tags: bolts, stripped-thread

I over-tightened the following bolt on my metering assembly.
[image: Axo of metering assembly picturing the bolt which I've over-tightened.]

The bolt now looks like this — you'll notice that it isn't too damaged but I've certainly done some damage.

[image: Damage of bolt near the tip showing some stripping.]

I am tempted to simply order a new bolt, re-insert more gently, and tighten it down. But I am concerned I might then place the assembly itself in jeopardy, and that's a far harder thing to just replace.

Given the damage on the bolt, what might a pragmatic mechanic more experienced than I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue using that bolt, I would grind that damaged section down , just like some bolts that have a lead on them.

Of course, before trying it again I would run a tap into the hole to clean that thread. If you have a replacent bolt the hole thread would need cleaning anyway.

If you don’t have a tap, an old bolt can be made into a « tap » with a cut from a hacksaw.. A trick that can rescue one out in the field when sources are limited.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've ordered a replacement bolt already. Is it as simple as putting grooves in like pictured [here](https://content.instructables.com/pdfs/EZP/Y2G1/GTGZI9MY/Make-a-tap-from-a-bolt.pdf)? It looks like the threads on the bolt end are tapered in addition to having been notched. Need I do that? If so, looks like I should grind down the first few thread levels and then notch it as pictured. Let me know if you'd recommend differently.